# Do I need to handle transaction in c# app layer as well database store process for single insert as well multiple insert

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

Do I need to handle transaction in C# app layer as well database stored procedures for single insert as well multiple insert?

**C#**

```
try
{ 
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted })) 
    {
         //Call Data Access Layer---Executing S proc
         transaction.Complete(); 
         return result; 
    } 
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
     throw new Exception(); 
}
```

SQL stored procedure:

```
Create process
As
Begin try
    Begin transaction
    Commit
End try
Begin catch
    Rollback
End catch
```

Comment: Refer here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93258/are-we-required-to-handle-transaction-in-c-code-as-well-as-in-store-procedure  you can get more clarification about this topic

Comment: Not pertinent to your problem, but your `catch` block is ludicrous - you're throwing away all pertinent information about the cause of the exception.  Just let the exception bubble up if you're not going to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you consider the responsibilities of each component here.

Your stored procedure has its task to do. If the stored procedure has multiple statements that must all be executed, then yes, the procedure should create & manage its own transaction.

For example, if the stored procedure's task is to update a user's email address and then generate an audit record, then both of those steps should be in a transaction inside the procedure. That transaction is necessary for the procedure to do its task.

However, your application might have a task that is bigger than a single stored procedure - you might be doing a task that requires *multiple* procedures. In that case, the application should create and manage a transaction *for the application's task*.

It (generally) won't do any harm if your application creates a transaction every time you call a stored procedure. But that's not really the point of managing transactions on the application layer. The point of creating transactions on the application layer is to string together a *set* of operations.

If you find that your application layer is usually doing complex operations that correspond one-to-one with stored procedures, you may want to re-think your architecture.